# Any reason not to always log stack traces?

Tags: java, logging, stack-trace

Encountered a frustrating problem in our application today which came down to an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception being thrown.  The exception's type was just about all that was logged which is fairly useless (but, oh dear legacy app, we still love you, mostly).  I've redeployed the application with a change which logs the stack trace on exception handling (and immediately found the root cause of the problem) and wondered why no one else did this before.  Do you generally log the stack trace and is there any reason you wouldn't do this?

Bonus points if you can explain (why, not how) the rationale behind having to jump hoops in java to get a string representation of a stack trace!

Comment: Was this legacy using `Log4J`? If so, was it using `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender`? I use it in banking applications (and yes, the system is huge) and I had no problems whatsoever.

Comment: From the question it doesn't seem as if he had any problem logging the entire stack trace; instead he seems to be asking why the developer who came before him did not do it that way.

Comment: @danben - correct, the question is about general practices regarding the logging of stack traces rather than how to do so.

Comment: I *always* try {...} catch (Exception e) { Logger.Error(e); } for exceptions that I don't know how to handle otherwise. generating the stacktrace is rather slow, but that shouldn't matter since such errors shouldn't happen very often anyway.

Comment: Some uses `logger.info()` or `logger.debug()` to pass "useful" information to log. Hence logging necessary/unnecessary data (depends on your POV) can be debatable. I was asking because it seems that there is too much info passing to the logger and it also seems that the developer never utilised the logger to its best efficiency.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman - there is no issue with logging performance in our application and we don't happen to use Log4J.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Some logs might contain sensitive data, log facilities are not necessarily secure enough to track that data in production.
- Logging to much can result in too much information, i.e. no information at all for the sysadmins. If their logs are filled up with debug messages, they won't be able to recognize suspicious patterns. (Years ago I saw a system logging all system calls for security reasons. There were so many logs, that nobody saw it when some unprivileged users started to become root.)

Best thing to do to log everything with appropriate log levels, and be able to set log levels in production (at least in Java not that a big issue).

Comment: Not sure how a stacktrace could contain sensitive info

Comment: @matt b: Already knowing particular class names is information enough to build up an attack vector (you remember that bug in Hibernate Validator x.y.z...) In security if you can't imagine a scenario, it is better to assume the worst.

Comment: I don't remember that bug but I'd be interested in seeing a description of it if you have a link.

Comment: This is not a real bug. Just if you tell everyone what classes you are using, it makes it a lot easier to find a bug for that specific library to attack on.

Comment: We do _two_ logs.  One at info level, and one at debug level, and the info level is deliberately quite silent.  This means that the initial investigator of a given problem, can look in the INFO log to get an overview and hopefully resolve the actual issue on the spot.  The DEBUG log is for the maintainer needing to do code fixes based on what happened back in time.  This distinction has worked very well for us.

Comment: If you properly index your logs and make them searchable (isn't having something like Splunk a must nowadays?), the too-much-information argument is irrelevant

Answer (score 3):

Please see these questions also

[Logging in Java and in general: Best Practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906233/logging-in-java-and-in-general-best-practices)

[Best practices for Java logging from multiple threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565893/best-practices-for-java-logging-from-multiple-threads)

Important things here to consider

1. Handling Sensitive data
2. Compact exception messages and mailing those to appropriate fixers
3. Logging what is required. Because its logging expensive in terms space
   and time

Answer (score 2):

I generally do log the stack trace, because it has information for troubleshooting/debugging the problem. It's the best think next to a minidump and often leads to a solution simply by code inspection and identifying the problem.

BTW, I agree with sibidiba about the potential information disclosure about your app internals a full stack exposes: the function names, along with the stack call sequence, can tell a lot to an educated reader. This is the reason why some products only log the symbol address on the stack, and rely on the devs to resolve the address to the name from internal pdbs.

But in I reckon that logging text into files containing 1 line of error and 14 lines of stack makes it very difficult to navigate the error logs. It also causes problem on high concurency apps because the lock on the log file is held longer (or worse, the log files get interleaved). Having encountered these problems my self many times, along with other issues in supporting and troubleshooting deployments of my own apps, led me to actually create a service for logging errors at [bugcollect.com](http://bugcollect.com). When designing the error collection policies I chose to collect the stack dumps every time, and to use the stacks as part of the bucket keys (to group errors that happen on the same stack into same bucket).

Answer (score 1):

Restrictions on logging are often pushed through when developers log too liberally and sysadmins discover that the app, once put under a production load, thrashes and fills the HD with huge log files. It can then be hard to convince them that you've seen the error of your ways and have reduced logging (or adjusted log levels) sufficiently but *really* need those remaining log entries.

Comment: Yep, definitely agree, but I can't imagine creating huge log files with stack traces.  If that's the case, then perhaps large logs files aren't your biggest problem :)

Comment: @Chris: probably yes, but when working on the innards of some module of a big system, it's easy to lose sight of the bigger picture and believe something an exceptional case that ends up happening a dozen times per second in production.

Answer (score 1):

For us it is very simple: If there is an unexpected exception thrown, we log the stack trace along with as telling a message as possible.

My guess is that the developer who wrote the original code in the question, simply wasn't experienced enough to know that it is not enough with just the message.  I thought so too, once.

The reason why it is convoluted to get a stack trace as a string is because there is no StringPrintWriter in the JRE - I believe the line of thinking has been that they provide a lot of orthogonal building blocks which you then combine as needed. You have to assemble the needed PrintWriter yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> Bonus points if you can explain (why,
>   not how) the rationale behind having
>   to jump hoops in java to get a string
>   representation of a stack trace!

Shouldn't you just log the throwable instead of going through hoops to print the stacktrace? Like this: log.error("Failed to deploy!", ex). Given a throwable, Log4J will print both the error message obtained via getMessage() and the stack trace.

Comment: As commented above, I'm not using Log4J

Answer (score 0):

What I've seen a lot is code logging an exception like this:

> LOG.error(ex);

Because log4j accepts an Object as the first argument, it will log the String representation of the Exception, which is often only the name of the class. This is usually just an oversight on the developer's part. It's better to log and error like this:

> LOG.error("foo happened", ex);

..so that if configured properly, the logging framework will log the stack trace.

Comment: Not sure why everyone here has the impression I'm using Log4J!