# Java Logging to Multiple Files

Tags: java, logging

I have an application which keeps track of multiple students.  When processing infromation on that student, I want their log messages to go into that log file.

```
logs/system.log
logs/abby.log
logs/brett.log
logs/catherine.log
```

The system can add more students dynamically, so I can't specify each student in my log config file.  How can I, at runtime, specify that a logger should write information to catherine.log ?

Answer (score 0):

Which Logging Framework are you using? Here is an example if you are using Log4j:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout;
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;

public class MyTestClass {
   /* Logger Instance should always be kept static final */
   private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyTestClass.class);

   public static void main(String args[]) {

      /* Create Dynamic FileAppender */
      SimpleLayout myLayout = new SimpleLayout();    
      FileAppender nwAppender = new FileAppender(myLayout,"file_nm",false);    

      LOGGER.addAppender(nwAppender);

      LOGGER.setLevel((Level) Level.INFO);

      /* Write Level : Debug */
      LOGGER.debug("*** DEBUG ***");
      /* Write Level : Info */
      LOGGER.info("*** INFO ***");
      /* Write Level : Error */
      LOGGER.info("*** ERROR ***");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm using java.util.logging.  If I need to use a different framework in order to get this to work I will.  Otherwise I'm reluctant to change the logging throughout my program.

Comment: There is no need to change anything. You can start using SLF4J with Log4J and simply bridge JUL to SLF4J. More Information: http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j

Comment: In your example code, would I need to create a new logger for each file I wished to write to?  If I simply added multiple FileAppenders to a single logger the log messages would go to all files, no?

Comment: Yes, If you add multiple FileAppenders to a single Logger then your message will go to all the files.

Comment: My intent is to write to multiple files.

Comment: Same content to multiple files or different content to different-different files?

Comment: My program spins up lots of threads at once.  At any point, multiple threads could be working on one student.  I tried this approach and two things don't work for me: 1) Messages for abby.log are simultaneously written to the system log and to abby.log. 2) If multiple threads are processing abby, it will open up abby-1, abby-2, etc.

Comment: Log4j is the probably the best practice  for multi threaded applications. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565893/best-practices-for-java-logging-from-multiple-threads

Answer (score 0):

> How can I, at runtime, specify that a logger should write information to catherine.log ?

There is no logging.properties option to enable this behavior.  You have to write code to create a logger (strongly referenced) and installed a FileHandler on that logger.

> Messages for abby.log are simultaneously written to the system log and to abby.log.

You should create a logger namespace such that the system file handler is installed on the root logger and each student is a child logger with [setUseParentHandlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#setUseParentHandlers(boolean)) set to false.

> If multiple threads are processing abby, it will open up abby-1, abby-2

That is because you are created multiple FileHandlers with the same file name.  Create a Map and remember what you have opened.

Comment: Create a map of the file handlers?  Should this be static and passed into my threads somehow?

Comment: Right.  Otherwise, if each student has a unique logger then check it if it has a file handler installed on the logger by calling logger.getHandlers.