# How to get total time taken by single thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 100 files. Some files size are 1mb and some files size are 100mb. I want to read all files utilizing multi-threading and I want to know how much time a particular thread has taken to read a single file. Lastly, I want to print the time of that thread out.

Note : I don't want average of single file.

Comment: You could have each thread log its start and end, assuming the logging framework you use supports multithreading.

Comment: To add to @TimBiegeleisen 's comments you should reference   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565893/best-practices-for-java-logging-from-multiple-threads  Also, consider setting logging for your imports.

Comment: Multithreading will only improve your performance between 2 to 4 threads depending on your drive type. Beyond that, more threads will yield poorer performance. There is a list of possible implementations in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40597140/3867574

Answer (score 2):

**Overview**

So there are a few ways you could achieve this that depend on the level of accuracy you would need. Lets investigate below.

**currentTimeMillis()**

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
// Your File Operation Logic
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timeElapsed = end - start;
```

This approach measures [wall-clock time](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/wall-time-real-world-time-or-wall-clock-time) so this could yield some inaccuracies, but for testing purposes this would likely be adequate. In addition, this will return the `timeElapsed` in **milliseconds**.

**nanoTime()**

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
// Your File Operation Logic
long end = System.nanoTime();
long timeElapsed = end - start;
```

This method differs from `currentTimeMillis()` because it measures in **nanoseconds**. In addition, the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--) state:

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time

**Instant & Duration**

```
Instant start = Instant.now();
// Your File Operation Logic
Instant end = Instant.now();
long timeElapsed = Duration.between(start, end).toMillis();
```

These class' are immutable, thread-safe, and utilize their own time-scale. However, you  must be on **Java 8** or higher to utilize.

**Implementation**

- For the thread operations, wrap the method that performs the file actions that you wish to measure with the above logic blocks.
- I recommend creating a **thread-safe** collection (your implementation may vary) of *time values* that will be printed out at a later time. Utilizing print statements when measuring time/performance will yield very inaccurate results, and should be used **after** your calculations have occurred.